# Plugin 0 specified, provided an invalid property of "default" (Jest React Native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs

Hey all I am just trying to get a simple test running and I keep running into this error after running "yarn test" which is using jest.

```
Plugin 0 specified in "/Users/Documents/Dev/appname/node_modules/babel-preset-react-native/index.js" provided an invalid property of "default" (While processing preset: "/Users/Documents/Dev/appname/node_modules/babel-preset-react-native/index.js")

  at Plugin.init (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/plugin.js:131:13)
  at Function.normalisePlugin (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:152:12)
  at node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:184:30
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at Function.normalisePlugins (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:158:20)
  at OptionManager.mergeOptions (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:234:36)
  at node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:265:14
  at node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:323:22
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at OptionManager.resolvePresets (node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:275:20)
```

Here is my package.json, what am I missing, im sure its a configuration issue and not a test issue.

```
{
  "name": "appname",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "resources/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-code-push": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.0.0-beta2",
    "react-native-form-validator": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.9",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^2.2.18",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-remote-svg": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-version-number": "^0.3.5",
    "react-navigation": "^2.11.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^5",
    "jest": "23.5.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

don't know if you solved that already but I had the same issue and I was able to make things work again with RN 0.56. I changed this:

```
"babel-preset-react-native": "^5",
```

to

```
"babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
```

here's the full discussion around the issue: https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/3897

if the above breaks your react-native env, another solution would be to install babel-bridge:

```
npm install babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0 --save-dev
```